# Regex - disallow www in email address

Tags: regex, email, email-address

I am using a regular expression to validate email addresses in an online form. A lot of emails are entered as such: `www.test@example.com`

How can I disallow the use of www. using regex? My current expression:

```
^[\+_a-z0-9-'&=]+(\.[\+_a-z0-9-']+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$
```

I know this expression checks for a gTLD - we require an email address to have one.

EDIT: This question is slightly different to others I have found as I wasn't sure how to add the `www` exclusion in - that's all I needed.

Also, the target market we reach doesn't have the same experience using technology as most people do, so the amount of email addresses that we receive with `www` in them is massive. `www.john@gmail.com` is perfectly valid yes but it is 99% of the time not what the persons email address is. Our CRM system can't send emails to the correct people then.

Comment: [Please don't use a regex to validate an email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46155/4519059). If you have a specific situation let us know it by adding some examples and results ;).

Comment: BTW, You can use a negative look forward like `^(?!www\.)...` ;).

Comment: I am aware of the negatives of using a regex, however the addresses we are validating are very simple address like `test@example.com`. We need the gTLD as people often forget them. Having said that, we do not need just domain addresses such as `test@example`, while it is valid, our target market does not use them. In the odd case one or two might it will be a far less amount that the number of people who forget a .com for example.

Comment: So a regex like [`^\w+@\w+\.[a-z]{2,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/y7tnTN/1) will fit your needs ;).

Comment: Why do you want to do such thing? `www.test@example.com` is a perfectly valid email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
^(?!www\.)[\+_a-z0-9-'&=]+(\.[\+_a-z0-9-']+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IvyaRo/1/)